# Using Fragments and Creating "Starting Page"

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm new in Android App developing via Java. I'm using Eclipse. If I create an Activity, Eclipse automatically generates a Placeholderfragment Class and Fragment.xml. Can I disable this function? Or is it not advisable to do that? I delete those files because I find it more complicated to use than just write in one xml file at the moment.

Second question is how do I implement a "starting Page" for my App? For example some sort of a logopage which automatically disables after a few seconds and switches to a new activity. Create a separate Activity for it or do I use something else?

Comment: Your second question is regarding a splash screen. It violates the android design pattern and is not recommended. Read more here: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/help.html#your-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you need two activities, one startup Activity which is used to show your logo or some guide,the other is a MainActivity which should be started by the startUp Activity.

Answer (score 0):

**In short You can do something like this**:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    Fragment fragment;
    String className;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Store the name of the class
        className=MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

        //First fragment should be mounted on oncreate of main activity
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {  
            /*fragment=FragmentOne.newInstance();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).addToBackStack(className).commit();
            */

            Fragment newFragment = FragmentOne.newInstance();  
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();  
            ft.replace(R.id.container, newFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();  
            Log.d("FRAGMENT-A", "fragment added to backstack");
        }
    }
}
```

**FragmentOne.java**

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment{

    String className;

    public static FragmentOne newInstance(){
        Log.d("FragmentOne", "newInstance");
        FragmentOne fragment = new FragmentOne();
        return  fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("FragmentOne", "onCreateView");
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        //Store the name of the class
        className=FragmentOne.class.getSimpleName();

        return view;
    }
}
```

***Let me know if you need any more info***

Answer (score 0):

Well, in a Single Activity setup, the way I did this was the following:

```
public class SplashFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private volatile boolean showSplash = true;

    private ReplaceWith activity_replaceWith;

    private Button splashButton;


    public SplashFragment()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try
        {
            activity_replaceWith = (ReplaceWith) activity;
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e)
        {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Activity of " + getClass().getSimpleName() + "must implement ReplaceWith interface!", e);
            throw e;
        }
        startSwitcherThread();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_splash, container, false);
        splashButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_splash_button);
        splashButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void startSwitcherThread()
    {
        Thread splashDelay = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    long millis = 0;
                    while (showSplash && millis < 4000)
                    {
                        sleep(100);
                        millis += 100;
                    }
                    showSplash = false;
                    switchToFirstScreen();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        splashDelay.start();
    }

    private void switchToFirstScreen()
    {
        activity_replaceWith.replaceWith(new FirstFragment());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if(v == splashButton)
        {
            if(showSplash == false)
            {
                switchToFirstScreen();
            }
        }           
    };
}
```

Where the ReplaceWith interface is the following:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public interface ReplaceWith
{
    public void replaceWith(Fragment fragment);
}
```

And the replace function is implemented like so:

```
@Override
public void replaceWith(Fragment fragment)
{
    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
        .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
}
```

Now, most people will say this is not a good approach if you're using multiple activities, and/or using multiple orientations and aren't just simply displaying a single Fragment in a single Activity no matter what. And they are completely right in saying so.

Multiple orientations would require the Activity to be responsible for knowing what is the "next" Fragment at a given replace call, and where to place it (which container, or to start it in a new Activity). So this is a valid approach only if you are certain that you only have *one* container and there is *one* Fragment shown at a given time.

So basically, if this does not apply to you, then you need to utilize the same approach (make a specific delay before you replace the current Fragment or Activity with another one, this specific code allows you that once the splash has been shown once, then clicking the button will automatically take you to the next screen - typical game splash setup, really), but use activity callbacks specific to the Fragment in order to swap one out for the other.

A Fragment setup I recommend and isn't relying on this special case can be seen here: [Simple Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840509/why-does-the-new-adt-create-a-static-inner-class-fragment-by-default-simple-fr) 
or its equivalent on Code Review: [Fragment Start-Up Project](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57543/why-does-the-new-adt-create-a-static-inner-class-fragment-by-default)